# GJS gnome-shell exception error, how to overcome this error

Tags: gnome-shell, gjs

I would like to learn what this error message is.

```
imports.ui.dateMenu.DateMenuButton.prototype.hide()
```

When I run above in lookingGlass, I get below error

```
<exception Error: Can't convert to pointer on .Gjs_ui_dateMenu_DateMenuButton.prototype; only on instances>
```

Can any one explain in detail.

Thanks.

Comment: in my opinion you should include minimal, reproducible example

Comment: @Drdiyor thanks for your comment. Added screenshot.

Comment: Please copy and paste your code instead of pasting a screenshot — it shows up really small and I can't read the tiny white-on-black text without zooming in!

Comment: Have done the copy and paste.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

JavaScript has *prototypal inheritance* — meaning that `DateMenuButton.prototype` is an object that contains DateMenuButton's methods, but it is not a DateMenuButton itself. So when you call `DateMenuButton.prototype.hide()`, you are calling DateMenuButton's `hide()` method on an object that is not a DateMenuButton. This will give you an error. The error message is not particularly clear but "can't ___ on prototype, only on instances" is a hint about what's going on.

To call this method, you will need an actual DateMenuButton object.

Here is some further reading material on prototypal inheritance: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Inheritance_and_the_prototype_chain